# Generate a sequence of coin flips until pattern is hit

Tags: strings, random, scala

A book on probability says that a sequence of heads and tails is generated by a fair coin asking what is the probability that the pattern T, H, H, H occurs before the pattern H, H, H, H. I have made a generator of such strings. Is it right (I have heard that return statement is not appreciated in Scala)?

```
def l(s: String): Boolean = {
    if (s.endsWith("hhhh")) return true; 
    if (s.endsWith("thhh")) return false; 
    l(s + (if (Math.random > .5) "h" else "t"))
}
```

Comment: I"m not sure what you're trying to do here. you need to toss the coin four times to get that sequence. if you do 4 x 1,000,000 attempts using a fair coin how many times will you get THHH and HHHH? Compare those two amounts. IF they are roughly similar then it's likely the coin is fair. if there is a great disparity between the two numbers, then its more likely than not that the coin is biased.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon The function that I posted for review generates a single sequence, up to "hhhh" or "thhh". You do not need to review anymore. And, just for your information, the fair coin generates thhh 15 times more often than hhhh. Gambler's fallacy [does not apply here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gambler%27s_fallacy&oldid=621549463#Non-examples_of_the_fallacy). Try yourself `(1 to 20) map (_ => l(""))` and see how more often true comes out than false. But, it does not matter for review.

Comment: that's very interesting. thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `return` statements:

```
def l(s: String): Boolean = {
  if (s.endsWith("hhhh")) true
  else if (s.endsWith("thhh")) false
  else l(s + (if (Math.random > .5) "h" else "t"))
}
```

Although I don't like `if` - `else if` sequences, in this case it remains simple and readable, but it still can be simplified like this

```
def l(s: String): Boolean = {
  if (s.length > 3) s.endsWith("hhhh")
  else l(s + (if (Math.random > .5) "h" else "t"))
}
```

or even

```
def l(s: String): Boolean = {
  s.endsWith("hhhh") || l(s + (if (Math.random > .5) "h" else "t"))
}
```

#### Randomness

I think that there is a *minor* issue with random values distribution.

As per Scaladoc for [`Math.random`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/index.html#random():Double):

> Returns a Double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

For the current condition, this means that 0.5 < h < 1.0 and 0 <= t <= 0.5.

0.5 is not included in the lower bound for generation of `h` values, which favors `t` very slightly.

The condition for equal distribution should be `if (Math.random < 0.5) "t" else "h"`.